# Bind type to generic method or constructor

Tags: c#, generics, types, ninject, bind

I got a specific factory which creates (inside its own assembly) some interface implementation:

```
public static IDataSource<T> CreateDataSource<T>(DataContext dataContext) { ... }
```

And I need to use it inside my [`nInject`](http://www.ninject.org/) kernel binder. The binding that is required looks like `IDataSource<T> -> Factory.CreateDataSource<T>(dataContext)`.

But the problem is that the following won't compile:-

```
kernel.Bind(typeof(IDataSource<>))
    .ToConstructor(ctx =>(Action<DataContext,>)Factory.CreateDataSource)
```

I've tried some other similar thing but can't get them to compile either. In any case (my guess) I need this `T` generic type to specify.

```
kernel.Bind(typeof(IDataSource<>))
    .ToConstructor(ctx  => Factory.CreateDataSource(ctx.Inject<DataContext>()))
```

This still fails to compile since it is needed in that `T` type.

How can I Bind to that kind of method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. `ToConstructor` expects a constructor such as `GenericDataSource<MyData>()` which won't work with open generics. Use `WithConstructorArgument` instead.